# Error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Tags: android

Please how do I fix this error?

I've tried every possible way. I know there must be a duplicate `onCreate` method somewhere but I can't see how to solve it. I tried removing the second instance and I still got a could not resolve error.

```
package com.service.campusplusstore;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Web1);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://cptvstore.com.ng");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-7372205449350361~4807793067");
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate onCreate in the code you paste here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `onCreate()` methods. Merge them:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Web1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://cptvstore.com.ng");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-7372205449350361~4807793067");
}
```